# Remove column from IQueryable in C# after include

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I'm including an entity object inside an other entity object like this:

```
string[] columnsToRemove = { "Insurance" };
var myQuery = _dataService.GetQuery<Insurance>().Include(i => i.Partner);
```

I need to remove a column inside `myQuery` because I get a circular reference on the client when parsing as JSON (`Insurance` has a column for `Partner` and `Partner` has a column for `Insurance`) but I don't want to use anonymous type definition because I need to create a method that accept an `IIncludedQueryable<T,U>` and return an `IQueryable` without the columns that I pass to method with the list of string.

Something like:

```
IIncludedQueryable<Insurances, Partner>RemoveColumnFromQueryable(typeOf(myQuery) myQuery, string [] columnsToRemove)
{
    // Here I want remove the column(s) from "myQuery"
}
```

Need something like this but this code is only for the idea:

```
IIncludedQueryable<Insurances, Partner>RemoveColumnFromQueryable(typeOf(myQuery) myQuery, string [] columnsToRemove)
{
    var attributes = myQuery.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var attribute in attributes)
    {
        foreach (var column in columnsToRemove)
        {
            if (attribute.Name != column)
            {
                // Remove the column from query
                newQuery = myQuery.Where(t => t.GetType().GetProperty(column).Name != column);
            }
        }
    }

    return newQuery;
}
```

Comment: You have already asked this question.

Comment: As for the reference loops - check the second duplicate. In short - the most robust approach is to use DTOs.

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you (the second one mentions DTOs) - feel free to accept and/or upvote them.